# VPN Config Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

i need to know if the following scenario is possible using Google Cloud:

I need to have a IPSec VPN with a partner, the thing is that at their side they will allow only one of my hosts access their network, at their side they configure a ACL as follows: network-object host X.X.X.4.

So, is a must that in the negotiation of phase 2, Google Cloud send as local address the ip number allowed by their X.X.X.4, and not the network X.X.X.0/something, if that happens phase 2 will crash.

Is possible to configure the VPN using this requirement?

Regards,

Will.

Answer (score 3):

1. You could try creating a /30 network in your project and hosts the VM that you would like to interact with the partner and setup the VPN tunnel
2. If you have another network, where other VM/Apps exists, setup a cross-vpn between the VPN tunnels in your project, just that they are in different network within the same project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, can u please share a link or something with documentation about making the connection between two existing networks?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn describes how to setup VPN. Following the same instructions, across 2 network within the same project would help accomplish the configuration you had wanted.  Thanks.

Comment: pls make sure you open up the firewall settings in the both the network once the vpn is setup. Routes don't have to be tampered, as VPN creation adds the routes as well